# Find parent value in dataframe "tree" structure

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe ("`mytable_df`") like this:

```
ID1     ID2     ID3     value
a       NA      NA      300
a       1       NA      50
a       2       NA      30
b       NA      NA      400
b       1       NA      60
b       1       1       20
```

Essentially this is a tree structure where (for example) row 2 and 3 are children of row 1, row 5 is a child of row 4, and row 6 is a child of parent in row 5.

For each row, I'm trying to identify the value from the immediate parent, with the 'root' rows, 1 and 4, just having their own value... to give me:

```
ID1     ID2     ID3     value    parent
a       NA      NA      300      300
a       1       NA      50       300
a       2       NA      30       300
b       NA      NA      400      400
b       1       NA      60       400
b       1       1       20       60
```

I've tried using a combination of case_when and apply statements but I can't work out how to compare current row with parent row etc.

Help! (please!)

*edit Additional from Freddy's request:

Ok; `tree` is my dataframe and `url1 - 4` are my IDs

```
case_when (
                is.na(tree$url2) ~ tree$n,
                is.na(tree$url3) ~ tree$n[tree$url1 == tree$url1 & is.na(tree$url2)],
                is.na(tree$url4) ~ tree$n[tree$url1 == tree$url1 &
                                          tree$url2 == tree$url2 &
                                          is.na(tree$url3)],
                TRUE             ~ tree$n[tree$url1 == tree$url1 &
                                          tree$url2 == tree$url2 &
                                          tree$url3 == tree$url3 &
                                          is.na(tree$url4)]
                )
```

so in the [] conditions, I want the first tree$url1 to be scanned across the dataframe and match the second tree$url1 which refers to the specific row.

Comment: What you tried post that also, then only it will give clear view

Comment: Edited above question. I didn't realise it was that bad a question to receive 6 downvotes; the example I hope covers the issue fairly well!